# Nuxt dynamic image - Require is not defined

Tags: browser, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In the Nuxt documentation they gave the code example below for dynamic image loading.

```
<img :src="require(`~/assets/img/${image}.jpg`)" />
```

However, when I use it I get the following error in the browser console "**Require is not defined**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my question as it took me a whole day of searching...

Apparently **'require()' works for Webpack only and doesn't work with Vite**.
And as Nuxt3 comes by default with Vite it wasn't working with me.

So to there are 2 options for fixing this issue:

1. Change from Vite to Webpack.
2. Use the code below instead of what's described in the Nuxt documentation to import dynamic images.

```
// in HTML
<img :src="getImageUrl()"/>

// in script
function getImageUrl(name) {
  return new URL(`./dir/${name}.png`, import.meta.url).href
}
```

**Useful sources**:

- https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url
- https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/12797

Comment: Nice, please mark your question as accepted when you can.

Comment: This doesn't work on my end. I get the error "Not allowed to load local resource:" when I load my SSG site using `nuxt dev`

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers not working for SSR.

An alternative is to use **Dynamic Imports**

Here's an example:

```
<template>
    <img :src="icon" alt="" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
async function resolveImage(name: string) {
  const module = await import(`~/assets/images/${name}`);
  return module.default;
}
const icon = await resolveImage();
</script>
```

References:

- https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import

Comment: This worked for my SSG site. But it's so cumbersome. I'm just using this to pass a resource path which is statically defined in one component into its child component. Isn't there a simpler way?